# Could broken air filter seal/gasket impair intake?

Tags: air-intake, air-filter

I am getting a `P0101: Mass or Air flow Circuit` and noticed that my air filter gasket is getting dangly in places, which might be causing it not to seal well. Could that be causing impaired air intake, which then triggers the code? The filter itself doesn't look too bad, i.e. not much dust or gunk collected on it.

Comment: Which one is your air filter gasket?  The one that holds the air filter to the intake manifold so all the air goes through the filter?

Comment: Realistically, since it's actually the circuit which is bad, that's not something which should be thrown due to a leak of any kind. That would throw a different code. This has to do with the connection, not with how much air is or isn't going through the MAF.

Comment: So replace the connector?

Comment: Hey @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 -- but [this page](https://www.samarins.com/diagnose/p0101.html) says that suction/pressure/vacuum could be a cause:

Comment: Even so, your leak is *before* the MAF, so would have no affect on what the MAF is reading, nor would (IMHO) throw that code because of it.

Comment: https://www.obd-codes.com/p0101

Comment: that page says: "possible causes: Intake air leaks"

Answer (score 1):

The air filter gasket (sealing surface to ensure air must pass through air filter) will not cause a code unless the engine is explicitly designed to monitor for the gasket integrity (I can't think of a car that's ever done this), and if it were to it would not be this code.

There are a few things that could cause this.
Faulty wiring/connector, or a faulty MAF/AFM Sensor.

Find out what the specific cleaning procedures for the MAF/AFM in your car, and check the connections.

You haven't put your Make and Model of car so I can't help you with this part, but you should research into diagnostics procedures for your cars MAF/AFM.